# Issue with regular expressions while parsing source code

Tags: regex, python-3.x, web-scraping

Im trying to get some information from a page source code.

For example, lets take this amazon product.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07PWCJZJ6?pf_rd_p=2d1ab404-3b11-4c97-b3db-48081e145e35&pf_rd_r=0PF9KX04Y9GAPGCXBDAP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PWCJZJ6)

We can check the source code with

view-source:[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07PWCJZJ6?pf_rd_p=2d1ab404-3b11-4c97-b3db-48081e145e35&pf_rd_r=0PF9KX04Y9GAPGCXBDAP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PWCJZJ6)

My objective is to get some data like the product descriptions (1366x768 LED display for example)

Im basically taking the whole source code and then using regular expressions to get the data I need.

Im doing something like this:

```
import requests

    source = requests.get(someUrl)
    data = re.findall(r'<span class=\"a-list-item\">(.*?)<\/span><\/li>', source.content)
```

Which should give me every product description, but I keep getting the `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`

I don't know if my regex is wrong or `source.content` is not giving me the source code

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for parsing HTML, in general.  Read about the Beautiful Soup library for Python for a better option.

Comment: I think clarify exactly what info you want from the page rather than a general "every product description"... For example, are you expecting the entire comparison table at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the diagnostic explains, the regex library wants a string input, not bytes.

The `requests` [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) is pretty clear:

> ... access the response body as bytes, for non-text requests:
>
> ```
> >>> r.content
> ```

Given that you retrieved some HTML text
you will want to decode it,
or let the library decode it for you:

```
>>> source.content.decode(source.encoding)
```

or

```
>>> source.text
```

Both expressions return a Unicode string,
which would be the *perfect* input for that regex.

Separate item: make [Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), not Regexes -- `bs4` is the more appropriate tool, here.